# SELECT association of tags and items

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm playing around with a tags DB, and want to know how to build a query to get a list of tags, marking each one that is applied to a given item, like this:

```
Table 1
item name   | item ID
---------------------
One         | 1
Two         | 2
Three       | 3

Table 2
tag name    | tag ID
--------------------
Tag1        | 1
Tag2        | 2
Tag3        | 3

Mapper
tag ID      | item ID   | map ID
--------------------------------
1           |  1        | 1
1           |  3        | 2
3           |  1        | 3

Tags for item One
tag name        |  is_tagged
-------------------------------
Tag1            | *
Tag2            |
Tag3            | *
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one simple method:

```
select t.tagname,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from mapper m join
                               items i
                               on m.item_id = i.item_id
                          where i.item_name = 'One' and
                                m.tag_id = t.tag_id
                         )
             then '*' else ''
        end) as is_tagged
from tags t;
```

You can also write this using `left join`s:

```
select t.tagname,
       (case when i.item_id is not null then '*' else ''
        end) as is_tagged
from tags t left join
     mapper m
     on m.tag_id = t.tag_id left join
     items i
     on m.item_id = i.item_id and i.item_name = 'One'
```

Comment: Terrific, thanks! I got so wrapped up learning about INNER JOIN, I forgot all about the other types of JOINs.

Answer (score 0):

You could make left or right join of *Table 2* and *Table 1* through *Mapper* table,  then test columns of *Table 2* for `NULL` values. For example:

```
SELECT 
   TagName, ItemID IS NOT NULL AS IsTagged
FROM 
   Table2 
   LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT TagID, ItemID 
   FROM Mapper INNER JOIN Table1 
   WHERE ItemName = 'One') AS tmpQry
   USING(TagID);
```